# How to know if Looper is running?

Tags: java, android, loops

Sometimes i catch this exception:

`Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

How to know if `Looper.myLooper()` called prepare?

ps - my english is not good

Answer (score 5):

If you call `Looper.myLooper()` it will return `null` if no prepare was yet called. To check this look into sources:

http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Looper.java

Answer (score 1):

Call [Looper.myLooper()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#myLooper()) from within the thread of interest. If it returns `null`, then the looper is not prepared for that thread.